# Python 2.6 -> Python 3.1 (for using ttk)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6, ttk, python-3.1

I want to use ttk as part of tkinter but I had Python 2.6 on my Mac. Therefore I went and installed Python 3.1, which has ttk come with it, and it did not overwrite the previous version. Therefore I still do not have the ability to use ttk.

Am I going about this wrong or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you successfully install Python3.1? Can you run it with `python3`?

Comment: I opened the package and went through the install process and it installed correctly. Is there another step after that, that I am missing?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `python3` do you get an interactive prompt such as `>>> `?

Comment: Yes I do get that. does this mean when I compile I use python3 instead of python?

Comment: It means when you want to *run* your script you should call it with `python3`.

Comment: is there a particular reason you chose Python 3.1? 3.3 is the current release - download from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/)

Comment: Other sources I was reading said to use Python 3.1 therefore I did not seek out a further version of it. But I could download 3.3. Are there significant differences between the 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Save the following in `test.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkk

class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        title = kwargs.pop('title')
        frame = tkk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
        frame.pack()
        self.label = tkk.Label(frame, text=title)
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)    

root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(root, title='Hello, world')
root.mainloop()
```

Then, at the terminal prompt, run

```
% python3 test.py
```

(To run a Python3 script, use `python3`. To run a Python2 script, use the `python`.)

Comment: That wont compile for me and I am trying to post a screen shot of my error. But I am new to stackoverflow and I am not sure how to do so. However these are two of the errors I am getting.

app = SimpleApp(root, title='Hello, world')

frame = tkk.Frame(master, **kwargs)

Comment: I need 10 reputation in order to post photos

Comment: Just copy and paste the text. That would be much better than a photo in this case anyway.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    app = SimpleApp(root, title='Hello, world')
  File "test.py", line 7, in __init__
    frame = tkk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/ttk.py", line 761, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    _load_tile(master)

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/ttk.py", line 47, in _load_tile
    master.tk.eval('package require tile') # TclError may be raised here
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tile

Comment: The last line of the error message says that `Tcl` can not find the `tile` package. You need to upgrade your version of Tcl. I don't have any experience with OSX, but I think [this page](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/) might help you.

Comment: I updated my `Tcl` and I am getting the same error. Unless there is a different way I should compile it now.

Comment: Your Python3 might still be linked to the old Tcl. Perhaps try reinstalling Python3 and watch to make sure it finds the new Tcl.